# download pdf servlet using content disposition not working fine with IE, chrome and firefox but not in Opera

Tags: pdf, servlets, download, cross-browser, content-disposition

I m using content disposition to download pdf file from my servlet. My code works fine for chrome, firefox and IE but the problem is when I try to download pdf file using opera, it removes pdf extension and adds htm. The following is my code:

```
        String filename = "abc.pdf";
        String filepath = "/pdf/" + filename;
        System.out.println("filepath "+filepath);
        resp.addHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);

        ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
        InputStream is = ctx.getResourceAsStream(filepath);

        System.out.println(is.toString());
        int read = 0;

        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        OutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();           
        while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            os.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        System.out.println(read);

        os.flush();
        os.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            logger.error("Exception occurred while downloading pdf -- "+ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println(ex.getStackTrace());
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably set the content type of the response to `application/pdf`, to let the browser know that the downloaded file is not a HTML file, but a PDF file.

See [`ServletResponse.setContentType()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType%28java.lang.String%29).